# AngularJS: Why does $element.find('option') return an empty array when using ng-options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, jqlite

In Angular 1.4, I am using the `ngOptions` directive to populate a `<select>` tag with `<option>` tags based on an object that looks like this:

```
{black: '#000000', red: '#FF0000', ...}
```

That works fine using `ng-options="value as key for (key, value) in vm.colors"`, but now I want to add a class to each option tag that matches the key (e.g. '.black', '.red'). My thought was to simply find the `option` elements and use `addClass()`, but I'm having trouble getting those elements. (Note: I'm not using jQuery and would like to avoid adding it just for this.)

[Here is a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/tfxauxzh/)

I expect to be able to bind the results of `$element.find('option')` to my view model and then watch it using `$scope.$watch('vm.options', function() {...})`, but when I log `vm.options` to the console all I am seeing is an empty array.

Am I using `$scope.$watch` incorrectly here? Is it an issue with `$element`? Are the elements within the scope of `ngOptions` unreachable from my controller? Or am I just making a stupid mistake?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you try using ng-class rather than using $element.select?? and using watch is not a good strategy always. it may slowdown your application

Comment: I agree about not wanting to use $watch, that's just where my troubleshooting led me. Can you show an example of how you would use ngClass in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this issue is specific to jqLite based on this comment in the source code: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.0/src/ng/directive/ngOptions.js#L382-L385

Comment: It is definitely a binding issue, where my options variable is not triggering an update during the digest. In this fork of my original jsfiddle, I am able to get the options using a button with ngClick: http://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/x1bh3jmL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was trying to watch the results of a function that returned `option` elements, but what I should have done was watch a function that returned the `length` property: `$element.find('option').length`.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/1rLLstfo/) that behaves as I had originally expected.

The clue that ultimately tipped me off was [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.0/src/ng/directive/ngOptions.js#L486) in the `ngOptions` code, which reminded me that "ngModel only watches for object identity change".

That answers my question, but as @jme11 pointed out, you can't style `option` elements so it doesn't help me achieve my goal.

However, this looks like it might: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) are pretty clear that DOM manipulation should only be done in a directive.  I use this rule of thumb: if I find myself wanting or needing to use angular.element, then I need a directive.

In this case, you can use the built in ngStyle directive:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    
    var hexColors = {
        black : '#000000',
        red   : '#FF0000',
        green : '#00FF00',
        blue  : '#0000FF'
    };
    
    angular.module('sandbox', [])
        .constant('hexColors', hexColors)
        .controller('SandboxController', SandboxController)
    ;
    
    function SandboxController($element, $scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.colors = hexColors;
        vm.selected = '#000000';
       
    }
    
})();
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sandbox" ng-controller="SandboxController as vm">
    <select ng-model="vm.selected" ng-options="value as key for (key, value) in vm.colors"></select>
    <p ng-style="{'background-color': vm.selected, color: 'white'}">Hex: {{ vm.selected }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm aware of when to use a directive, but what I'm actually trying to do is modify the output of the ngOptions directive...and whether I try doing it from a controller or another directive, the result is the same. Unfortunately, I can't use ngStyle because I'm not trying to style an element in my markup. Rather, I'm trying to style the option tags that ngOptions is creating.

Comment: I'm trying to apply a class to each option tag based on the corresponding key in the hexColor object. More specifically, I want to apply a background color equal to the value, so I guess style could work -- but I don't want to manually write CSS rules for each color in the object. Furthermore, I want to understand why this isn't working as expected.

Comment: My question was more about the practical side.  You can't style options in a select, so why are you trying to add a class to it.  I suppose the only way you could do it if you wanted to would be to not use ngOptions and build your own directive to append the options.

Comment: My original idea was to prefix the label with a color square, using :before CSS selector, but I hadn't gotten to the point where I might have realized you cannot style items in the drop down list because I was sidetracked by the issue of not seeing the option elements when $watch'ing for them.